# Apex Class - findnearby - missing angle bracket

Tags: apex, class

I have implemented a trigger and class to get geolocation fields filled in Accounts with the help from this site 
[make geolocation available](http://www.vandeveldejan.com/trigger-geolocation-account-google-map-nearby-accounts/#comment-89)

Then i wanted to use the findnearby function in addition and added the Apex Class as following

> ```
> global with sharing class FindNearby {
> public FindNearby(ApexPages.StandardController sc){}
> @RemoteAction
> // Find Accounts nearest a geolocation
> global static List getNearby (String lat, String lon) {
> // If geolocation isn't set, use Eindhoven (or any other city)
> // Put a default location latitue and longitude here, this could be where you are located the most
>     // and will only be used as a backup if the browser can not get your location details
>     if(lat == null || lon == null || lat.equals('') || lon.equals('')) {
>         lat = '51.096214';
>         lon = '3.683153';
>     }
>      // SOQL query to get the nearest accounts
>     //you can change km (kilometers) into mi (miles)
>     // < 20 means within a radius of 20 km or mi (you can change that)
>     //limit 25 shows 25 records (you can adapt that too if you want)
>     String queryString =
>         'SELECT Id, Name, Location__Longitude__s, Location__Latitude__s, ' +
>             'BillingStreet, Phone, BillingCity ' +
>         'FROM Account ' +
>         'WHERE DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') < 20 ' +
>         'ORDER BY DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') ' +
>         'LIMIT 25';
>      // Run and return the query results
>     return(database.Query(queryString));
> }}
> ```

but then, I got the Error, that in line 5 an left angle bracket is missing Error Code in detail: "expecting a left angle bracket, found 'getnearby'
when i added a left angle bracket, it tells me "unexpected token: '('

Do you have any clue, what am i missing here? I originally copied the class text from the website without any change to it.

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Ralf

Comment: You are returning a List of .... Accounts, the syntax is like so: List<Account>

Comment: Hi Mihai, but this code is exactly like in the thread from the website, where other users don´t have problems with. Can this maybe caused by Salesforce updates, as this thread is from older 2014

Comment: Maybe it's a typo on the website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global static List getNearby (String lat, String lon) {` you need to change this line into

```
global static List<sObject> getNearby (String lat, String lon) {
```

try this and update if it is works for you.